# Responsive mixin in LESS

Tags: less-css

I wrote a responsive mixin for Less when I couldn't find a full featured one. Curious what other developers have done to solve this problem and hoping to improve/reduce my code since I'm very new to Less:

It would be invoked like:

```
element {
    overflow: visible;

    .responsive(768px, 0, min, {
        overflow: hidden;
    });
}
```

Args are: `width`, `height`, `min|max`, `rules`
This would set `overflow: hidden` for > 768px. You could also set `max` in the declaration to set `overflow: hidden` for < 768px.

```
.responsive(@width: 0, @height: 0, @type: min, @rules) {
.responsive-max() when(@type = max) {
    .responsive-max-full() when(@width > 0) and (@height > 0) {
        @media only screen and (max-width: @width) and (max-height: @height) {
            @rules();
        }
    }
    .responsive-max-width() when(@width > 0) and (@height < 1) {
        @media only screen and (max-width: @width) {
            @rules();
        }
    }
    .responsive-max-height() when(@width < 1) and (@height > 0) {
        @media only screen and (max-height: @height) {
            @rules();
        }
    }
    .responsive-max-full();
    .responsive-max-width();
    .responsive-max-height();
}
.responsive-min() when(@type = min) {
    .responsive-min-full() when(@width > 0) and (@height > 0) {
        @media only screen and (min-width: @width) and (min-height: @height) {
            @rules();
        }
    }
    .responsive-min-width() when(@width > 0) and (@height < 1) {
        @media only screen and (min-width: @width) {
            @rules();
        }
    }
    .responsive-min-height() when(@width < 1) and (@height > 0) {
        @media only screen and (min-height: @height) {
            @rules();
        }
    }
    .responsive-min-full();
    .responsive-min-width();
    .responsive-min-height();
}
.responsive-max();
.responsive-min();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating it. Typically, I think Less users just write the media queries inline with a variable. As in:

```
@tablet-min: ~"only screen and (min-width: 768)";

element {
  overflow: visible;

  @media @tablet-min {
      overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```